# Not able to access an XML Element using .innerHtml with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

this is my first post here so I hope that I do this right. I have searched for a day or so now and I haven't been able to find any direction so far so I guess it's time to ask. I am not able to access an element in my XML file. I can load the XML file, and get it saved into a variable and then in the debugger I can navigate to the information that I want to load into my DOM but when I try to access it using ".innerHtml" it is returning an empty string. I have also tried making sure that I am pointing to the correct node(?) inside of the XML Element by adding the [0] location to the "batch".

Here is my function:

function getBatchNumber(xml){

```
        let batchHTML = document.getElementById('batch');
        let batch = xml.getElementsByTagName('DIALOG5');
        var test = batch[0];
        batchHTML.textContent = test.innerHtml;
        //batchHTML.textContent = "3151414";
    }
```

In the debugger when I hover over "test" I can see that innerHtml is in the tree and has the correct number I am after. Then when I hover over innerHtml it is showing me that it has a value of "".

Thank you for any help or insight into this.

Comment: `innerHtml` should be `undefined`, not an empty string. The property is called `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you Quentin! I feel pretty silly right now but that was it.